# Key letters? Option letters? What are these things?

Tags: arguments

Some GNU and GNU-like tools seem to accept options in a combined manner, e.g. `foo -hgcf` instead of `foo -h -g -c -f`.

[An example is tar](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch38_12.htm), as in `tar cXbf keepout 20 archive.shar *.txt` instead of `tar -c -b 20 -X keepout -f archive.tar *.txt`.

I was under the impression that this "compressed" or "short" style of specifying arguments had a name. Does anyone know what it's called, how I can learn more about it, and how to find out if a tool supports it?

Comment: perl's `Getopt::Long` calls it "bundling".

Comment: The tar example is different because it groups _all_ of the options together, whereas the conventional style does not allow options that have arguments to be grouped together. You couldn't do `foo -hxgczf 10 12` in place of `foo -h -x 10 -g -c -z 12 -f` - that's something only tar does (well, i think there are a handful of other programs that do it too)

Comment: `tar(1)` is a _particularly_ bad example, as it has its own, very idiosyncratic flag parsing. Another egregious outlier is `sort(1)`. There are surely others...

Answer (score 3):

In traditional Unix, options were one letter, like `ls -l` or `ls -d`. In some cases the option would take an argument, as in `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` (`-d` (delimiter) with value `:`, `-f` (fields to select) with value `1`). Where the options didn't take arguments, instead of `ls -l -d -F /tmp/*` you can write `ls -ldF /tmp/*`. Some commands take options starting with `+`, like `more +10 file` starts `more(1)` on line 10 of `file`.

I believe it was the GNU project around '87 or so who introduced the idea of long options, like `cut --delimiter=: --fields=1 /etc/passwd` means the same as the cryptic command above in GNU's `cut`. This gives quite more readable options, and works around there being *only* 62 letters and digits, which is much too few options for e.g. `ls(1)`... thus we have `gcc -c -O2 --fomit-frame-pointer xxx.c` and such.

Some heretic commands use long options starting with just `-`, like `convert -adjoin -authenticate passwd some.jpg graphic.gif files.png -o here.pdf` (from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), the `-adjoin` places the images together, the `-authenticate` takes a password; this is just smashed together from the manual page's options list, this combination might make no sense).

Many commands (but not all, and it depends on what Unix flavor is your poison) take `--` to mean "following isn't options anymore, even if it looks like options", so with GNU's `rm(1)` you can get rid of the `-rf` file commonly created as a stupid prank by `rm -- -rf`.

Comment: `find` seems like another good example of such a heretic command.

Comment: This is a lot of useful info that seems to miss answering any of the actual questions that were asked

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, oops... never wondered what the smashing several flags together might be called, just used it as a nice shortcut since way back when...

Answer (score 0):

In C see [`getopt_long`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html) and in `bash` look for [`getopts`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)